# Valid way to detect path platform

Tags: python, cross-platform, pathlib

The Python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library [automatically detects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pathlib.py#L632) the platform it's running on to construct (Pure)Path objects. This makes sense when operations have to execute system calls (this object class are called "concrete classes" in the documentation).

Functionality that appears to be missing is to be able to detect whether a path is a Windows or Posix path. For "C:\home\user\file.txt" and "/etc/" we could do this based on the separators and/or drive. I'm aware that this task is ambigious for relative paths, we constrain ourselves to absolute paths.

What would be a valid way to detect the path type in python, preferable in the pathlib context?

Comment: as I know in Python on Windows you can also use `/` in path and it will work - even without drive - ie. `/home/user/file.txt` but I would assume that Windows uses \

Comment: The Explorer app does not recognize "C/Users/" as a valid path, but does recognize "C:/Users/". Assuming this as a constraint, we are able to use the drive.

Comment: I don't use Windows for years but I think it should recognize `/Users/` without drive - at least in console/terminal/cmd.exe with command `cd` - `cd /Users/` - if you already works on drive `C:`

Comment: Indeed, if you already work on drive `C:`. This is considered a relative path (by the question definition).

Comment: Why do you want to detect to what platform a path belongs to?
if you explain the exact problem / use case you might perhaps find a different solution.

`os.sep` / `os.path.sep` gives you the separator of the os your code is running on
`os.platform` / `platform.release()` gives you the platform on which your code is running on

with `if '\\' in path` you can assume the path is a windows path>
with `if '/' in path` you can assume the path is a non windows path, though it is a path, that would work on windows platforms as well.

Comment: Note that “C:\home\user\file.txt” is a valid (relative) POSIX filename (with no directory separators).